# jq inner array value as new key outside the array

Tags: arrays, jq, flatten

Input:

```
{
"data": {
    "assets": [{
            "organizationId": "1056bda9-2598-4fdf-bd99-db3924464a75",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-14T14:41:41.154Z",
            "tags": [{
                    "value": "raml",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "rest",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "api",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "v1",
                    "key": "product-api-version",
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "has-mule4-connector",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "has-mule3-connector",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "system",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "sourcing",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": true
                }
            ],
            "type": "rest-api"
        },
        {
            "organizationId": "SASAAs",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-14T14:41:41.154Z",
            "tags": [{
                    "value": "raml",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "rest",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "api",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "v1",
                    "key": "product-api-version",
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "has-mule4-connector",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "has-mule3-connector",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "system",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "supply-chain",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": true
                }
            ],
            "type": "rest-api"
        }   
    ]
}
```

}

Expected output:

```
{
"data": {
    "assets": [{
            "organizationId": "1056bda9-2598-4fdf-bd99-db3924464a75",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-14T14:41:41.154Z",
            "tags": [{
                    "value": "raml",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "rest",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "api",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "v1",
                    "key": "product-api-version",
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "has-mule4-connector",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "has-mule3-connector",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "system",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "sourcing",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": true
                }
            ],
            "type": "rest-api",
            "domain": "sourcing"
        },
        {
            "organizationId": "SASAAs",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-14T14:41:41.154Z",
            "tags": [{
                    "value": "raml",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "rest",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "api",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "v1",
                    "key": "product-api-version",
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "has-mule4-connector",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "has-mule3-connector",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": false
                },
                {
                    "value": "system",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "supply-chain",
                    "key": null,
                    "mutable": true
                }
            ],
            "type": "rest-api",
            "domain": "supply-chain"
        }   
    ]
}
```

}

SO far, I tried this which worked partially for me.

**.data.assets[] | select (.tags[].value=="sourcing") | . += {"domain":"sourcing"}**

The problem is that I want this condition to apply for every object inside the array but I'm not able to do that. It is getting applied to the first object only.

Where am i doing wrong? Any suggestions please?

Comment: you need to specify the position in `.data.assets[]` .

Comment: There is a mismatch between the given output and the stated goal. 
 Where does `"domain": "supply-chain"` come from???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to meet the descriptive requirements:

```
.data.assets |=
  map( if any(.tags[].value; . == "sourcing")
       then . + {"domain":"sourcing"}
       else .
       end )
```

This produces the desired output except for the key-value pair `"domain": "supply-chain"` that is inconsistent with the descriptive requirements.

The following, by contrast, takes its cue from (that is, produces) the given output:

```
.data.assets |=
  map( if any(.tags[].value; . == "sourcing") then . + {"domain":"sourcing"}
       elif any(.tags[].value; . == "supply-chain") then . + {"domain":"supply-chain"}
       else . end )
```

#### Setting "domain" to all the tag values

```
.data.assets |= map( .domain += [.tags[].value] )
```

Comment: This is exactly I'm looking for! 100% served my purpose. Thank you so much. But I'm no able to run this command from inside bash script? Anything wrong? `echo $response | jq .data.assets |= map( if any(.tags[].value; . == "sourcing") then . + {"domain":"sourcing"} else . end )`

Comment: You would have to add suitable quotation marks (e.g. echo “$response” | jq ‘...’), or use the -f command-line option.  See the jq manual for details.

Comment: It was my mistake earlier. I corrected the quotes and it working like charm. Upvote! I have around 6 `elif` conditions. To avoid this, is it feasible to declare array as in `arr["marketing","supply-chain","sourcing"]` and compare and achieve the same output?

Comment: Yes, it’s possible, and easily done once you master jq’s basics. Meanwhile, you indicated an intention to upvote ....

Comment: I did upvote. They said it can’t be visible right now!

Comment: Will you be able to give an example on array?

Comment: Please look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553691/jq-add-capturing-group-result-outside