# jq add capturing group result outside

Tags: json, regex, object, jq, capturing-group

For example,

Input:

```
    {
       "id":"abc",
       "name": "name-middlenane-lastname-1"
    },

    {
        "id":"123",
        "name": "fname-flast-2"
    }
```

response:

```
    {
         "id":"abc",
         "name": "name-middlename-lastname-1",
         "newkey": "name-middlename-lastname"
    },

    {
          "id":"123",
          "name": "fname-flast-2",
          "newkey": "fname-flast"
    }
```

The filed **name** in each object is a string with characters and numbers separated by **"-"** hyphen. I need the complete string from beginning till the starting number. I don't want anything which is there after the number. And then the add **new** field with key as **newkey** and value should be extracted string without the number. Thus, the output should contain old fields as well as new one.

Comment: @peak any suggestions?

Comment: why does `"name": "name-middlename-lastname-1",` remain unchanged in your output? Check again your expected output

Comment: @naveenkreddy - please provide more precise requirements, e.g. what if `name` is “123-ab456” or “a1b”?

Comment: @peak and  RomanPerekhrest  updated even further. Is that clear now? please advice,

Comment: Updated problem statement @peak & RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577421/jq-update-json-key-being-value-of-some-key-and-value-being-value-of-some-other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

Sample `input.json`:

```
[
  {
    "id": "abc",
    "name": "name-middlenane-lastname-1"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "fname-flast-2"
  }
]
```

---

```
jq 'map(. + (.name | capture("(?<newkey>.+)-[0-9]+")) )' input.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "abc",
    "name": "name-middlenane-lastname-1",
    "newkey": "name-middlenane-lastname"
  },
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "fname-flast-2",
    "newkey": "fname-flast"
  }
]
```

Comment: @NaveenKReddy, I can easily update my solution if I knew the concrete requirements for the expected result

Comment: Perfectly worked for my example. Thank you RomanPerekhrest for saving my time! I think @peak also would have shown the similar command. Thank you guys!

Comment: can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647815/jq-group-by-and-increment

Comment: Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800086/jq-retain-missing-array-objects-from-capturing-group-and-update-array