# jq update json - key being value of some key and value being value of some other key

Tags: jq

> Sample **input.json**

```
    [{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "runtimeVersion": "3545",
    "type": "rest-api",
    "server": "test1",
    "status": "UP"
   }]
```

> Expected **output.json**

```
      [{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "runtimeVersion": "3545",
    "type": "rest-api",
    "server": "test1",
    "status": "UP",
    "test1": "UP"
  }]
```

The input is an array object. I need to add new key which is the value of key **server**. The value of this new key should value of the key **status**.

Any solutions on achieving this using **jq**

Comment: @peak I believe this is new question. Do you have any solutions please?

Comment: what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: @AndrewLohr I recently (as recent as last week) started learning jq. I've learnt how to iterate through and get the key and values. But this one seems tricky to me. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of Polya's "How to Solve It", let's start by observing that the fact that the object to be updated is in an array is a distraction, so let's focus on the task at hand:

> adding a key-value pair to a JSON object

"Add" is thus a helpful word to keep in mind, and indeed looking at the jq manual, you will find both "+" and "add".  If . is the starting object, then we could achieve the update by writing:

```
. + {(.server): .status}
```

(The parentheses around `.server` are necessary as `.server` has to be evaluated.)
The above expression is a filter, and the usual way of applying a filter to each member of an array is using `map`.  This leads to what might be the most "elementary" (as in "my dear Watson") solution to the problem:

```
map(. + {(.server): .status})
```

Another approach would be to use the "assignment syntax" to add (or modify) a key, leading to an even shorter solution:

```
map( .[.server] = .status )
```

Maybe that is no less elementary ...

Comment: The best explanation! Perfectly understood. Thank you so much for your time for explaining it to us!

Comment: One thing though.Can you please explain the difference between [.server] and (.server) and the simple use cases? I have seen (.server) evaluates it but confused with [.server] at the end of your post?

Comment: @NaveenKReddy - I'd suggest consulting the materials mentioned at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#tutorials

Comment: can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586355/how-to-compare-one-field-that-is-common-in-each-object-of-an-array-in-two-files

Comment: can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800086/jq-retain-missing-array-objects-from-capturing-group-and-update-array

Answer (score 1):

Simple **`jq`** approach:

```
jq '.[] |= . + {(.server):.status}' file.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "runtimeVersion": "3545",
    "type": "rest-api",
    "server": "test1",
    "status": "UP",
    "test1": "UP"
  }
]
```

Comment: Such a simple solution.! I didn't know about the (.server) adds key. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586355/how-to-compare-one-field-that-is-common-in-each-object-of-an-array-in-two-files