# how to compare one field that is common in each object of an array in two files and do update the array as well

Tags: merge, grouping, jq

> Sample **input1.json**

```
[{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "test1": "UP",
    "key1": "value1"
}, 
{
    "organizationId": "org2",
    "test1": "UP",
    "key1": "value3"
}]
```

> Sample **input2.json**

```
[{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "test2": "DOWN",
    "key1": "value4"
}, 
{
    "organizationId": "org3",
    "test2": "DOWN",
    "key1": "value5"
}]
```

> Expected **output.json**

```
[{
        "organizationId": "org1",
        "test1": "UP",
        "key1": "value4",
        "test2": "DOWN"
    },
    {
        "organizationId": "org2",
        "test1": "UP",
        "key1": "value3"
    },
    {
        "organizationId": "org3",
        "test2": "DOWN",
        "key1": "value5"
    }
]
```

The input is an array object of two files. My objective is to merge two objects if they have same value and leave other objects intact. I partially achieved this by grouping

`jq -s '[ .[0] + .[1] | group_by(.organizationId)[] | select(length > 1) |add ]' ìnput1.json input2.json`

Group objects by **organizationId**. In both the inputs, **"organizationId": "org1"** is available so it can be grouped. Now the problem I'm facing is I'm loosing other objects **"organizationId": "org2"** from **input1.json** and **"organizationId": "org3"** from **input2.json** which doesn't exist in each others file.

The basic principle of grouping is achieved but I do need to preserve any other objects from both the files even if there is no match. Should we use **group_by** if we want to preserve other objects? If not, how can I achieve the expected output using **jq**?

Comment: but your current approach preserves all other ungrouped objects and gives you the expected result. What is the issue?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks for spotting! I was trying different options and missed it! I updated the post with the one I tried and given answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For wider audience, solution to get all objects (grouped & ungrouped), use below

`jq -s '[ .[0] + .[1] | group_by(.organizationId)[] |add ]' ìnput1.json input2.json`

If only grouped objects, then use below.

`jq -s '[ .[0] + .[1] | group_by(.organizationId)[] | select(length > 1) | add ]' ìnput1.json input2.json`

I have to say **jq is so powerful**! :)

Comment: (1) `.[0]+.[1]` can in this case be simplified to just: `add`; (2) group_by is a bit tricky in that the sorting algorithm it uses in version 1.5 is NOT guaranteed to be stable.  A "stable" version was introduced on January 18, 2016.  If you are stuck with an older version, then you could use GROUPS_BY as defined at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321235

Comment: @peak Thanks for letting us know. We are using `1.5-1-a5b5cbe`. I hope this is stable? Am I right?

Comment: a5b5cbe dates from Aug 18, 2015 and therefore CANNOT be relied on for stability of sorting.

Comment: Thanks @peak I googled to install the latest package `sudo apt-get install jq`. Mine is debian. But I can't find out which version it will install. Is there any way to confirm the latest stable (please specify if you know) version before installing?

Comment: I believe apt-get will just get you jq 1.5.  Since I don't know your platform, all I can do is suggest that either you use the workaround I've already mentioned, or consult the jq Installation pages.

Comment: @peak While reading it's looks like pretty much I understood it. But I couldn't tweak it for my requirements.  :( I have added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647815/jq-group-by-and-increment. Will you be able to check please?