# jq group by and Increment at same time

Tags: arrays, json, grouping, jq

> Sample **input1.json**

```
[{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "status": "UP",
    "server": "server1",
    "somekey1" : "somevalue1"
}, 
{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "status": "DOWN",
    "server": "server2",
    "somekey2" : "somevalue2"
},
{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "status": "DOWN",
    "server": "server3"
},
{
    "organizationId": "org2",
    "server": "server1",
    "status": "UP",
    "somekey2" : "somevalue2"
},
{
    "organizationId": "org2",
    "server": "server2",
    "status": "UP",
    "somekey4" : "somevalue4"
}]
```

> Expected **output.json**

```
[{
        "organizationId": "org1",
        "server1": "UP",
        "server2": "DOWN",
        "server3": "DOWN",
        "Down_Count": 2,
        "somekey2" : "somevalue2"
    },
    {
        "organizationId": "org2",
        "server1": "UP",
        "server2": "UP",
        "Down_Count": 0,
       "somekey2" : "somevalue2"
    }]
```

The input is an array object of two files. My objective is

1. to increment and populate the new field `Down_Count` by grouping by `organizationId`. I can have multiple records with same `organizationId`. Hence, the count should be incremented that number of times subject to status `DOWN`.
2. Merge `server` and `status` fields. For example `"server":"server1", "status":"down"` should come as `server1:down` directly in final output. I can try this one independently using `jq '.[] |= . + {(.server):.status}'`
3. all the keys are not available in all the objects. Hence, I should be able to add the keys I want to the final output. Lets assume I know the key name I want to add. In the final output,  I have added only `"somekey2" : "somevalue2"`

I'm finding some difficulties to achieve all these together using `jq` cmd line processor. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Could you [edit] into your question some of the parts you've attempted, and information on where they went wrong?

Comment: @IMSoP I have given what I can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq 'group_by(.organizationId) 
    | map(reduce .[] as $o ({"Down_Count" : 0};
              if $o["status"] == "DOWN" then .Down_Count += 1 else . end
              | . + { ($o["server"]) : $o["status"],
                          "organizationId" : $o["organizationId"] }
          ))' input.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "Down_Count": 2,
    "server1": "UP",
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "server2": "DOWN",
    "server3": "DOWN"
  },
  {
    "Down_Count": 0,
    "server1": "UP",
    "organizationId": "org2",
    "server2": "UP"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This exactly helped! However, I need a slight tweak. I'm not add able to add other keys. For example, let's say `"key1":""value1"` is an additional key available only in any one object of `"organizationId": "org1"` How can I get this in the final output?

Comment: can you elaborate where should `"key1":""value1"` reside and where should it eventually be placed?

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly. Please check the third point as you have already given me first two.

Comment: @NaveenKReddy, whether a key name should be a single dynamic argument?

Comment: third question was asked as I couldn't figure out how to populate new filed if it is nested. That is for example, if `"server": "server1"` is coming as `"servers":{server": "server1"},` then when I add `($o["servers.server"]) : $o["status"]`, its not working. But I figured it as `($o["servers"]["server"]) : $o["status"]`.  Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach you could take:

```
group_by(.organizationId) | map(
    reduce ([., [range(length)]] | transpose[]) as [$o,$i] (
        {
            organizationId: .[0].organizationId,
            Down_Count: (map(select(.status=="DOWN")) | length)
        };
        reduce $keys[] as $k (
            .["server\($i+1)"] = $o.status;
            if $o | has($k) then .[$k] = $o[$k] else . end
        )
    )
)
```

Just pass in an array of keys named `$keys` you want to be copied over. If it exists in one of the objects, it will be copied to the result object.

```
$ cat input.json
[{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "status": "UP",
    "server": "server1",
    "somekey1" : "somevalue1"
}, 
{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "status": "DOWN",
    "server": "server2",
    "somekey2" : "somevalue2"
},
{
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "status": "DOWN",
    "server": "server3"
},
{
    "organizationId": "org2",
    "server": "server1",
    "status": "UP",
    "somekey2" : "somevalue2"
},
{
    "organizationId": "org2",
    "server": "server2",
    "status": "UP",
    "somekey4" : "somevalue4"
}]
```

```
$ cat program.jq
group_by(.organizationId) | map(
    reduce ([., [range(length)]] | transpose[]) as [$o,$i] (
        {
            organizationId: .[0].organizationId,
            Down_Count: (map(select(.status=="DOWN")) | length)
        };
        reduce $keys[] as $k (
            .["server\($i+1)"] = $o.status;
            if $o | has($k) then .[$k] = $o[$k] else . end
        )
    )
)
```

```
$ jq --argjson keys '["somekey2"]' -f program.jq input.json
[
  {
    "organizationId": "org1",
    "Down_Count": 2,
    "server1": "UP",
    "server2": "DOWN",
    "somekey2": "somevalue2",
    "server3": "DOWN"
  },
  {
    "organizationId": "org2",
    "Down_Count": 0,
    "server1": "UP",
    "somekey2": "somevalue2",
    "server2": "UP"
  }
]
```