# jq retain missing array objects from capturing group and update array

Tags: if-statement, jq

> **Input**

```
[{
        "tags": [{
                "value": "domain:sourcing"
            },
            {
                "value": "apiname:src1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "tags": [{
            "value": "apiname:fin1"
        }]
    },
    {
        "tags": [{
            "value": "domain:fin1"
        }]
    }
]
```

> **Expected output**

```
[{
        "domain": "sourcing",
        "apiname": "src1"
    },
    {
        "domain": "-",
        "apiname": "fin1"
    },
    {
        "domain": "fin1",
        "apiname": "-"
    }
]
```

So far I have tried below.

`jq 'map(. + (.tags[].value | capture("domain:(?<domain>.+)"))) | map(. + (.tags[].value | capture("apiname:(?<apiname>.+)"))) | map(del(.tags))'`

> **partial output from above cmd**

```
[
  {
    "apiDomain": "sourcing",
    "apiName": "src1"
  }
]
```

As you have seen, the problem here is I'm completely loosing the other objects if any one capturing group filed is absent. Second object in input has **apiname** but missing **"domain"** and third object has **"domain"** but missing **"apiname"**. As stated in the sample output, if any object doesn't present, then they should come as **"-"**.

Can the jq command be updated to achieve this please?

Answer (score 1):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq '{domain: "-", apiname: "-"} as $o 
    | map([.tags[] | .value | split(":") | {(.[0]) : .[1]}] | add | $o + .)' input.json
```

- `{domain: "-", apiname: "-"} as $o` - used as a *template* object

The output:

```
[
  {
    "domain": "sourcing",
    "apiname": "src1"
  },
  {
    "domain": "-",
    "apiname": "fin1"
  },
  {
    "domain": "fin1",
    "apiname": "-"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach. This assumes your `tags` array will only contain the names you expect.

```
map(
    reduce (.tags[].value | split(":")) as [$k,$v] (
        {domain:"-",apiname:"-"};
        .[$k] = $v
    )
)
```

---

For a more general solution that doesn't assume fixed names and just flattens the tags, I'd do this:

```
map(
    reduce (.tags[].value | split(":")) as [$k,$v] (
        del(.tags);
        .[$k] = $v
    )
)
```

Then as you access the fields, just use the alternative operator to set the default value.

```
(.domain // "-") as $domain
```

Answer (score 1):

If the "value" part of the "tag:value" strings might contain a colon (":"), then using `split` becomes unnecessarily tricky (and maybe even inefficient), so it might be easier to use `capture`, perhaps along the lines suggested by @RomanPerekhrest:

```
{domain:"-", apiname:"-"} as $default
| map([.tags[].value
       | capture("(?<k>[^:]*):(?<v>.*)")
       | {(.k): .v} ]
      | add
      | $default + .)
```